# Pipe video frames from ffmpeg to numpy array without loading whole movie into memory

Tags: python, numpy, ffmpeg

I'm not sure whether what I'm asking is feasible or functional, but I'm experimenting with trying to load frames from a video in an ordered, but "on-demand," fashion.

Basically what I have now is to read the entire uncompressed video into a buffer by piping through `stdout`, e.g.:

```
H, W = 1080, 1920 # video dimensions
video = '/path/to/video.mp4' # path to video

# ffmpeg command
command = [ "ffmpeg",
            '-i', video,
            '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
            '-f', 'rawvideo',
            'pipe:1' ]

# run ffmpeg and load all frames into numpy array (num_frames, H, W, 3)
pipe = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)
video = np.frombuffer(pipe.stdout, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(-1, H, W, 3)

# or alternatively load individual frames in a loop
nb_img = H*W*3 # H * W * 3 channels * 1-byte/channel
for i in range(0, len(pipe.stdout), nb_img):
    img = np.frombuffer(pipe.stdout, dtype=np.uint8, count=nb_img, offset=i).reshape(H, W, 3)
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to do this same process, in Python, but without first loading the entire video into memory. In my mind, I'm picturing something like:

1. open the a buffer
2. seeking to memory locations on demand
3. loading frames to numpy arrays

I know there are other libraries, like OpenCV for example, that enable this same sort of behavior, but I'm wondering:

- Is it possible to do this operation efficiently using this sort of ffmpeg-pipe-to-numpy-array operation?
- Does this defeat the speed-up benefit of ffmpeg directly rather than seeking/loading through OpenCV or first extracting frames and then loading individual files?

Comment: I'm not very clear on what the real problem is that you are trying to solve. I deduce it must be something to do with `ffmpeg` being too slow to seek maybe? How long does it currently take to seek, if that is the issue? How long are your videos in seconds and fps? How long do you typically work on them before loading a different one? I'm trying to understand what you really want to optimise and how you might make trade-offs to achieve it with more RAM, more disk, better-targetted data-structures.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Currently I am parsing a mp4, writing individual frames to file, and then reading those frames in various later processes. Definitely less than efficient, but these frames are needed at different stages in subsequent processes and I don't have the memory to store all frames in memory for the whole process. Because ffmpeg is so efficient for loading/parsing the mp4, I was thinking I'd skip the individual frame IO and just lean on ffmpeg. However, my initial solution above leads to a 100 second RGB video at 1920x1440 needing 24GB of RAM.

Comment: In short, I'm looking to keep memory needs low, but IO faster than individual frames. FWIW: iteratively reading and resizing 700 RGB 1920x1440 PNG files for one video takes ~150 seconds, but loading and filtering through ffmpeg takes about 8-10 sec. That observation is what prompted this effort.

Comment: Confused now. 1920*1440*3=8MB/frame. So if you have 700 frames you should need 5GB of RAM, not 24GB?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry I gave 2 examples without being clear: that 24GB example was for a 100 second, 30Hz video (3000 frames). The second example is the one I actually benchmarked, which was ~700 frames and produced those loading times.

Comment: Ok, have you considered 1) storing the frames in memory as YUV with the U and V channels chroma sub-sampled? That gives you full resolution Y (luminance) and half-resolution colour (U and V) which reduces RAM requirements by 50% relative to RGB. Or 2) reducing the colours to <256 colours which means you can use palettised images which only need 1 byte/pixel instead of 3 bytes of RGB per pixel thereby reducing your storage to 1/3 of RGB? Or 3) using Redis so you can harness RAM on other machines in your network?

Comment: Of course, you could save JPEGs in RAM too, maybe indexed by frame number, which would probably require less than 1/10th of the RAM and, given the performance of modern CPUs, you could likely get any frame within milliseconds.

Comment: This second idea is especially interesting. My concern with quantizing information in the first approach is that my application relies on some computer vision algorithms (as opposed to serving a purely visual purpose) for which this might cause unexpected behavior whereas JPEG artifacts don't seem to have a known impact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible, and relatively simple to seek and extract frames without loading whole movie into memory.

There is some speed-up loss, when the requested frame to seek is not a **key frame**.
When FFmpeg is requested to seek a non-key frame, it seeks to the closest key frame before the requested frame, and decodes all the frames from the key frame to the requested frame.

The demonstrating code sample does the following:

- Builds synthetic 1fps video with a running frame counter - perfect for testing.
- Execute FFmpeg as sub-process with stdout as an output PIPE.
  The code sample seeks to the 11'th second, and set duration to 5 seconds.
- Read (and display) decoded video frames from the PIPE until there are no more frames to read.

---

Here is the code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import subprocess as sp
import shlex

# Build synthetic 1fps video (with a frame counter):
# Set GOP size to 20 frames (place key frame every 20 frames - for testing).
#########################################################################
W, H = 320, 240 # video dimensions
video_path = 'video.mp4'  # path to video
sp.run(shlex.split(f'ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size={W}x{H}:rate=1 -vcodec libx264 -g 20 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 60 {video_path}'))
#########################################################################


# ffmpeg command
command = [ 'ffmpeg',
            '-ss', '00:00:11',    # Seek to 11'th second.
            '-i', video_path,
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',  # brg24 for matching OpenCV
            '-f', 'rawvideo',
            '-t', '5',            # Play 5 seconds long
            'pipe:' ]

# Execute FFmpeg as sub-process with stdout as a pipe
process = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)

# Load individual frames in a loop
nb_img = H*W*3  # H * W * 3 channels * 1-byte/channel

# Read decoded video frames from the PIPE until no more frames to read
while True:
    # Read decoded video frame (in raw video format) from stdout process.
    buffer = process.stdout.read(W*H*3)

    # Break the loop if buffer length is not W*H*3 (when FFmpeg streaming ends).
    if len(buffer) != W*H*3:
        break

    img = np.frombuffer(buffer, np.uint8).reshape(H, W, 3)

    cv2.imshow('img', img)  # Show the image for testing
    cv2.waitKey(1000)

process.stdout.close()
process.wait()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Note:
The argument `-t 5` is relevant when the playing duration is known from advance.
In case the play duration is unknown from advance, you can remove the `-t` and break the loop when needed.

---

**Time measurements:**

1. Measure reading all frames at once.
2. Measure reading frame by frame in a loop.

```
# 6000 frames:
sp.run(shlex.split(f'ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size={W}x{H}:rate=1 -vcodec libx264 -g 20 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 6000 {video_path}'))

# ffmpeg command
command = [ 'ffmpeg',
            '-ss', '00:00:11',    # Seek to 11'th second.
            '-i', video_path,
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',  # brg24 for matching OpenCV
            '-f', 'rawvideo',
            '-t', '5000',         # Play 5000 seconds long (5000 frames).
            'pipe:' ]



# Load all frames into numpy array
################################################################################
t = time.time()

# run ffmpeg and load all frames into numpy array (num_frames, H, W, 3)
process = sp.run(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)
video = np.frombuffer(process.stdout, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(-1, H, W, 3)

elapsed1 = time.time() - t
################################################################################


# Load load individual frames in a loop
################################################################################
t = time.time()

# Execute FFmpeg as sub-process with stdout as a pipe
process = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)

# Read decoded video frames from the PIPE until no more frames to read
while True:
    # Read decoded video frame (in raw video format) from stdout process.
    buffer = process.stdout.read(W*H*3)

    # Break the loop if buffer length is not W*H*3 (when FFmpeg streaming ends).
    if len(buffer) != W*H*3:
        break

    img = np.frombuffer(buffer, np.uint8).reshape(H, W, 3)

elapsed2 = time.time() - t

process.wait()


################################################################################

print(f'Read all frames at once elapsed time: {elapsed1}')
print(f'Read frame by frame elapsed time: {elapsed2}')
```

---

Result:

`Read all frames at once elapsed time: 7.371837854385376`

`Read frame by frame elapsed time: 10.089557886123657`

The result shows that there is some overhead of reading frame by frame.

- The overhead is relatively small.
  There is a chance that the overhead is related to Python and not to FFmpeg.

Comment: After testing this out, it certainly answers my question and serves the original desired purpose.