# how to efficiently decode h264 encoded rtsp stream and use it to opencv-python at 30 FPS

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, h.264

I'm just doing yolo object detection with opencv code snippet:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:asv@123@192.168.1.24:554/main?tcp", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
show = True
while show:
 
    ref, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.resize(img, (1024, 720))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    res = model(img)
```

so, this is a normal code snippet for yolo object detection with opencv and torch
It's working good on with USB webcam, video files etc.
But with the RTSP stream and h264/h265 codec the `cv2.VideoCapture()` cannot decode it efficiently(at 30 FPS). But if it's on 6 FPS,it can. But I need to do it on 30 FPS.
I saw some documentation, i.e. opencv VideoCapture officially doesn't support h264/h265 codec. so is there any way to decode h264 encoded stream efficiently at 30 FPS in python and the use it to opencv and object detection?
Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using OpenCV, you may try using FFmpeg command line interface with Python sub-process and pipe (or using Python binding to FFmpeg). Here is a [relatively simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67352282/pipe-video-frames-from-ffmpeg-to-numpy-array-without-loading-whole-movie-into-me). Using FFmpeg you may also get a grayscale frame resized to 1024x720 without using OpenCV and H.265 is not an issue. 30 FPS is not guaranteed... What is the resolution of the input video, what is the hardware configuration? CPU / GPU? How do you measure the FPS?

Comment: Hi Rotem, The hardware configuration is CPU >> intel i5. The input size is 1280x720. I'm configuring the FPS from the configuration dashboard of the IP camera

Comment: from the previous example I used

Comment: I used the ffmpeg format from the previous example, but unfortunately the image is staggered. can't understand anything in the image. Getting these some times `Last message repeated 1 times
frame=   92 fps=3.5 q=-0.0 size=  248400kB time=00:00:03.06 bitrate=663551.9kbit. [rtsp @ 0x560505018700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x560505018700] RTP: missed 726 packets
[h264 @ 0x56050505c280] error while decoding MB 33 1, bytestream -7
`

Comment: Does this help cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:asv@123@192.168.1.24:554//out.h264")? Didn't you add  cv2.waitKey(0)?

Comment: cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:asv@123@192.168.1.24:554/out.h264", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

Comment: The reason I asked about the hardware configuration is that there is an option to use hardware accelerators for video decoding (and for resizing). "CPU >> intel i5" is not detailed enough... In case you want to use FFmpeg directly (without OpenCV), you have do do some research (learn the the FFmpeg syntax and options). I recommend you to try using FFmpeg from command line first (before using it within Python).

Comment: you can try to switch to pyav and create a codec context for hw accl =)

Comment: @toyotaSupra Both methods are giving me the same output.

Comment: @Christoph do you have any tutorial link or code?